# Отправка формы на сервер

Tags: java, servlet

У меня есть метод:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("метод сработал");

    System.out.println(req.getRequestURI());

    final String id = req.getParameter("id");

    System.out.println(id);
}
```

И есть `jsp` файл который в форме его зовет:

```
<body>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="number" placeholder="id" name="id"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку `Submit` страница просто перезагружается и все. Не каких признаков что метод `doPost` отработал нет.Почему метод даже не вызывается не говоря уже о значении `id`?

Comment: У формы не указан атрибут `action`, поэтому она отправляет post-запрос этому же jsp-файлу, а не сервлету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы метод *doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
   HttpServletResponse resp)* отработал необходимо отправить POST
   запрос.
2. Для того, чтобы форма была отправлена на сервер POST запросом в ней необходимо 
   описать 2 атрибута: 1 **method = "POST"**; 2 **action = "*your_url*"**

Решение вашей проблемы: Добавление атрибута **action** c url, по которому хотите отправить запрос.